# Change color of bar on bar chart in ApexCharts based on .getMonth() === series Month

Tags: function, apexcharts

I have a Grouped Bar chart in Apexchart with 3 sets of data. I would like to change the color of the 3 bars in the group if the Data 1:Month > the current month. Not sure if I'm going in the right direction here... or if there's a way to get rid of the Data 1 and incorporate the months into the function.

Example:
Data 1: Months: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (This Data set will be hidden)

Data 2: Dividend Amount: 10,30,35,45,55,30,40,30,25,40,60,45

Data 3: Expected Dividend: 15,20,25,25,45,20,30,20,15,20,20,35

x: Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/D_Flighty/8osfpm47/198/)

`

```
colors: [
    function({
      value,
      seriesIndex,
      dataPointIndex,
      w
    }) {

      const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

      let i = w.config.series[0].data[dataPointIndex].Month

      if (i > currentMonth) {
        return '#e9184b'
      } else {
        return '#689642'
      }
    }
  ],
```

`

I tried searching stack overflow and the web, looked at other peoples examples on codepen. I tried different variations using the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
colors: [
   function ({ value, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
       if (dataPointIndex == Date.getMonth) {
        return "#7E36AF";
    } else {
       return "#D9534F";
       }
     }   ]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.